# Jquery Datepicker change year range after its initialization

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to change year range in datepicker after initialization. I have a generic code for datpicker

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonText: "Date Selector",
        buttonImage: "calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        timeFormat: "h:mm TT",
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: '1900:+10',
        changeYear: true
    });
});


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

i need to change the year range without changing the generic code, so the range changes only in one place. 
So after its initialized by a generic code the year to be changed to 2015:2016.
Any help?

Comment: create a jsfiddle.net of what you have so far.

Comment: oh and just fyi, anytime you post a question about code using a plugin, try and reference which plugin you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're using the *date**time**picker* plugin, but if it's the one I think it is, it's just an extension to jQueryUI's datepicker, therefor the following should work to change *year range*.

```
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "yearRange", "2002:2012" );
```

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonText: "Date Selector",
        //buttonImage: "calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        timeFormat: "h:mm TT",
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: '1900:+10',
        changeYear: true
    });
});

$('button').click(function(e) {
  
  /* L I K E  T H I S  */
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "yearRange", "2015:2016" );
  /* L I K E  T H I S  */
  
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

<button>change range</button>
```